# Draw a geometric object and texture in different coordinates using same shader in Opengl (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I wonder if there is a nice (at least any) way to draw some geometric shape and a texture using same shader program in opengl 2 (or maybe higher).

Saw this example in a book for a fragmnet shader (as an example of how glTexEnvi func from Opegl 1 can be replaced in Opengl >= 2 version):

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D s_tex0;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec4 v_primaryColor;
void main()
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_tex0, v_texCoord) * v_primaryColor;
}
```

Though it is very hard for me to guess the vertex shader, if i want to draw texture and some geometry in different coordinates (possibly intersecting in some place).

Does anybody have an idea?

There has to be a way. It will just make some things (for example different blendings) so much easier to do.

P.S. Had an idea of using a "switcher" in vertex shader to pass different coordinates wheather it is in "1" or "0" state, somewhy it didn't workout. Hope you know a better solution.

Comment: It’s a little unclear what you’re asking for. Shaders in OpenGL 2.0 and above are very flexible. Can you provide an example of the effect you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying make a transperent hole in a geometric primitive(№1) to look behind it (at another primitive (№2)). Hole shape is modulated with a texture alpha chanel.                 Hope at least this particular goal is clear.

Comment: Sounds like you want [alpha testing](http://content.gpwiki.org/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Ortho_and_Alpha#Alpha_Testing) and/or `discard`.

Comment: @gen Yep, but it seems to me, that there's more than that needed. (I  wasn't able to do the thing with single disccard )

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave it here.

Though i still don't know the possible vertex shader for the question above i was lucky enough to solve my subgoal a harder way using blending.

It turned out that blending with constants GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA didn't work as expected (when destination are vertices) because alpha channel for pixels was "turned off" by default (you could still use  alpha channel from image), so you have to "turn it on" to make blending with these constants work properly.
In android studio (and java overall) it is possible to do it using setEGLConfigChooser function.